# How to get a custom block form in another custom block?

Tags: 8, blocks

I have a custom block

```
/**
 * Provides block A.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "block A",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Block A"),
 * )
 */
class Block A extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  public function defaultConfiguration() {
    return [some_value]
  }

  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Configuration form
  }
}
```

Now I have another block

```
/**
     * Provides block B.
     *
     * @Block(
     *   id = "block B",
     *   admin_label = @Translation("Block B"),
     * )
     */
    class Block B extends AnotherClass {
    
      public function defaultConfiguration() {
        return [some_value]
      }
    
      public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $form = BlockA->buildForm()
        return $form;
      }
    }
```

The `AnotherClass` extends `BlockBase`.

Is it possible to display the `Block A` configuration form in `Block B`?

Like `$form = BlockA->buildForm()`?

The problem with @Clive comment is that `Block A` is from the contrib module. So I can't change its base class.

Comment: If the block classes share common functionality, they should inherit from the same base class. So yes, just move the form method into `AnotherClass`, and make sure `BlockA` and `BlockB` both inherit from it. There are several other ways to solve the problem of course, what you're asking about are just standard OO principles and how to implement them in PHP

Comment: The problem is `Block A` is from contrib module, so I don't have any control over it. @Clive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the `plugin.manager.block` service

Example:

In the `Block B` `BlockForm` method.

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $block_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
  $block_a = $block_manager->createInstance('block_a');
  $form = block_a->blockForm($form, $form_state)
  return $form;
}
```